# What's the different between the state_keep_prob and output_keep_prob parameters of tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper

Tags: python, tensorflow

According to the [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/DropoutWrapper) of `tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper`:

- `output_keep_prob`: unit Tensor or float between 0 and 1, output keep probability; if it is constant and 1, no output dropout will be added.
- `state_keep_prob`: unit Tensor or float between 0 and 1, output keep probability; if it is constant and 1, no output dropout will be added. State dropout is performed on the output states of the cell.

the description of these two parameters are almost the same, right?

I set `output_keep_prob` as default and `state_keep_prob=0.2`, the `loss` is always around `11.3` after 400 mini-batches' training, while I set `output_keep_prob=0.2` and `state_keep_prob` as default, the `loss` returned by my model quickly down to around `6.0` after 20 mini-batches! It cost me 4 days to find this bug, really magic, can anyone explain the difference between these two parameters? Thanks a lot!

hyper parameters:

- lr = 5E-4
- batch_size = 32
- state_size = 256
- multirnn_depth = 2

Here is the [dataset](https://github.com/thomasmesnard/DeepMind-Teaching-Machines-to-Read-and-Comprehend).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `state_keep_prob` is the dropout added to the RNN's hidden states. The dropout added to the state of time step `i` will influence the calculation of states `i+1, i+2, ...` . As you have discovered, this propagation effect is often detrimental to the learning process.
- `output_keep_prob` is the dropout added to the RNN's outputs, the dropout will have no effect on the calculation of the subsequent states.

Comment: Do you know what state_keep_prob is in the case of LSTM units? So to which parts of the units is it applied?

Comment: @Lemon In the literature it is either done on the outgoing state `h_t` or on the internal cell `c_t`. The tensorflow documentation mentions: _State dropout is performed on the outgoing states of the cell._ So it should be done on `h_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correctly mentioned as *output keep probability*, which one you should use depends on whether you decide to use *outputs* or *states* to compute your *logits*.

I am providing a code snippet for you to play around with and explore the use cases:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.reset_default_graph()

# Create input data
X = np.random.randn(2, 20, 8)

# The first example is of length 6 
X[0,6:] = 0
X_lengths = [6, 20]
rnn_layers = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(size, state_is_tuple=True) for 
size in [3, 7]]
rnn_layers = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell, 
state_keep_prob=0.8, output_keep_prob=0.8) for lstm_cell in 
rnn_layers]
# cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=64, state_is_tuple=True)
multi_rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(rnn_layers)

outputs, states  = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
                                     cell=multi_rnn_cell,
                                     dtype=tf.float64,
                                     sequence_length=X_lengths,
                                     inputs=X)

result = tf.contrib.learn.run_n(
{"outputs": outputs, "states": states},
n=1,
feed_dict=None)
assert result[0]["outputs"].shape == (2, 20, 7)
print (result[0]["states"][0].h)
print (result[0]["states"][-1].h)
print (result[0]["outputs"][0][5])
print (result[0]["outputs"][-1][-1])
print(result[0]["outputs"].shape)
print(result[0]["outputs"][0].shape)
print(result[0]["outputs"][1].shape)
assert (result[0]["outputs"][-1][-1]==result[0]["states" 
[-1].h[-1]).all()
assert (result[0]["outputs"][0][5]==result[0]["states"] 
[-1].h[0]).all()
```

`result[0]["outputs"][0][6:]` will be arrays of all 0s.

Both the assertions will fail in case when `state_keep_prob` and `output_keep_prob` are <1 but when equated to the same value say 0.8 as in this example you can see apart from the dropout mask they produce the same final state.

If you have variable `sequence_length` you should definitely use `states` to compute your logits and in that case use `state_keep_prob` <1 while training.

If you plan on using outputs(should be used in case of constant `sequence_length` or else it needs further manipulation to get the final valid state in case of variable `sequence_length` or you may need output at every time step) you should use `output_keep_prob` while training.

If `output_keep_prob` and `state_keep_prob` are both used with different respective dropout values then you will see different values in final returned states in `outputs` and `states` along with different dropout mask.